# How to display all available bluetooth devices in my ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I booted my new pc in ubuntu 20.04 but when I try to connect any Bluetooth device to my system but it didn't show any Bluetooth device in the setting?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you know for sure your machine has Bluetooth?

Comment: "How to display all available bluetooth devices " That is not how BT works. If there are it will only list -paired- devices. To pair you need to make sure the system has BT support and then turn BT on. Pairing a device will make it prompt for it (it differs ever so slightly per device how though)

Comment: How do I check that my system has Bluetooth?

Comment: `lspci` (for internal, like a WiFi+BT card) or `lsusb` (for external USB devices). One of them should provide a result. Please edit the question and post the `lspci` line result that identifies your WiFi card. If it's a model take includes Bluetooth we can then find out. If external, well, you should know what you connected or not.

Comment: I don't understand I'm really noob in Linux, so sorry 